# Is the renewal function really a distribution function?

Tags: stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

I often read that the renewal function $R(t)=\mathbb{E}(N_t)$ is a distribution function. But shouldn't a distribution function (CDF) be smaller than $1$?

Comment: Yes, CDF functions $P[X\leq x]$ have values between 0 and 1 and are not $E[N_t]$ functions.

Comment: "I often read ..."   So, give us an example of this.